# Shopware 6: Module parse failed: Unexpected token after running `./psh.phar storefront:dev`

Tags: webpack, sass, shopware

I want to add some custom SCSS code to my Shopware 6 plugin. Therefore I created a `main.js` file as entry point and imported my custom SCSS file. After running `./psh.phar storefront:dev` I got following error from Webpack:

```
ERROR in /app/custom/plugins/MyTheme/src/Resources/storefront/styles/custom.scss 2:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
   > .test {
    | 
    | }
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 2
    npm ERR! sw-next-storefront@1.0.0 development: `NODE_ENV=development webpack --config webpack.config.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 2
```

Answer (score 1):

With the EarlyAccess realese of shopware 6 we added the theme manager and with that an easy way to add custom styles.

Previously you had to bring your own webpack config, that explains the error.

Now shopware automatically imports and compiles all `*.scss` files located in your `<plugin root>/src/Resources/storefront/style`. As your `custom.scss` file is located in this folder it should be working out of the box with the current EA1 version of shopware.

Just delete the import of the `.scss` file from your `main.js` and update your shopware instance and you should be ready to go.

Detailed information on how to add custom js or custom styles can be found in the [Docs](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/storefront-assets#adding-styles).